# solidity mapping does not persist

Tags: solidity

solidity mapping does not persist

I have this solidity code

```
contract Starting { //pragma solidity ^0.6.12

    struct itemStatus {
        bool created;
    }
    mapping (bytes => itemStatus) public item;
    
    bool[] public boolArray;    

    function start(bytes memory itemId) public returns (bool[] memory) {
        boolArray.push(item[itemId].created);
        if (item[itemId].created) {
            boolArray.push(item[itemId].created);
            return boolArray;
        } else {
            item[itemId] = itemStatus(true);
            boolArray.push(item[itemId].created);
            return boolArray;
        }
    }
}
```

frontend javascript code is

```
  toStart: function () {
    let Instance;
    App.contracts.Starting.deployed().then(function (instance) {
      Instance = instance;
      return Instance.start.call(itemId);
    }).then(function (result) {
      console.log(result);
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
  },
```

The first time I call `toStart`, I would expect `[false, true]` and the second time I call with the same itemId `[false, true, true, true]` and third time `[false, true, true, true, true, true]`. However, the result is always `[false, true]` irregard how many times I call `toStart`. It seems `item[itemId] = itemStatus(true)` and `boolArray.push(item[itemId].created)` changes are never stored/persisted. Why is it so? How to change the code to get the expected result? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
Instance.start.call(itemId)
```

To this:

```
Instance.start.send(itemId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the ethers version you're using is the older version, the error arises because ethers.js makes a distinction between constant calls and non constant(state writing) calls using `call` and `send`. When trying to call a constant method, `call` is used and when calling a non constant method, `send` is used.

Because your contract changes the state in `boolArray.push(item[itemId].created);`, the function is non constant and you need to use the `send`.

**Ethers v5** : Ethers v5 does not make this distinction. You can call both methods the same way but the return values would be `Promise<any>` for constant and `Promise<TransactionResponse>` for non constant functions.